# Angular - Show datetime without timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime

I have a date with this format :

`this.visited_at: "2019-07-26T10:15:00+0200"`

I need to display the hour and minutes by ignoring the timezone.

Template :

```
<p>{{ time.visitedAt | date: 'HH' }} h {{ time.visitedAt | date: 'mm' }}</p>
```

The problem is that this converts the time according to the timezone of the machine.
I need to display exactly **10h15** and ignore all timezone conversion.

Comment: you have to calculate delta of system time right?

Answer (score 0):

This might work (assuming you will always receive the date in the same format):

```
visitedAt = '2019-07-26T10:15:00+0200';
timezone = this.visitedAt.substring(this.visitedAt.length - 5); // Get the timezone
```

```
<p>{{ visitedAt | date: 'HH \'h\' mm' : timezone }}</p> <!-- Format the date with the timezone you got from the date -->
```